# LTE internet with lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

so i tried to combine lte internet with home internet. one is ethernet and other is usb. i bridge them both but for some reason the ethernet always defaults. I run a speed test and only goes my max speed which is 8mbps. my phone is 20-25mbps down and upload is 12-15mbps. any one have experience in this?

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail, if you want someone to help.  What are you trying to achieve here?  What do we need to have experience with?

Comment: trying to make a super pipe to have both internets run at the same time so i can have faster speeds.

Comment: If the answer below answered your question, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand.  When you have wifi and ethernet enabled, the computers usually (not always) choose the wired ethernet connection to pass traffic because it is assumed to always have the faster speed.  If you are running Windows, there is an option to prioritize ports.  You can change and prioritize ethernet metrics.  You can find the reverse of what you are trying to achieve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785874/setting-network-adapter-metric-priority-in-windows-7)